# use a customize method on an Object

Tags: java, interface, observers

I've created an Interface named "Writeable", and every class that implements it should override the method returnFilePath - which returns a String - a path to the correct file path related to that class.
for Example:

```
public class PatientRepository extends Observable implements Writeable,Readable{
    private static final String filepath="src/files/patients.det";
    ...
    @Override
    public String returnFilePath() {
       return filepath;
    }
```

as you can see, this class also extends Observable. that class is observed by FileManager class:

```
public class FileManager implements Observer {

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    try (OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(????);
         ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)){
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(arg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

what i want to do is that in the FileOutputStream constructor i'll pass the correct file path, according to the Object i'm currently working on, but I can't get access to the returnFilePath() method i wrote.

what should i do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do is casting:

```
public class FileManager implements Observer {

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    try (OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( ((Writeable)o).returnFilePath());
         ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)){
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(arg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}